# Append new dict in list and check for duplicates

Tags: python

I want to count the dict in all_list which have the same `id` and `star`, and in the meantime, if `id_count` doesn't have this `id` and `star`, then add it into `id_count`.

My code:

```
id_count = [{'id': 33, 'star': 2, 'count': 3}]

all_list = [{'power': 20710, 'id': 33, 'skills': "", 'rank': 0, 'lv': 1, 'star': 2},
            {'power': 22296, 'id': 49, 'skills': "", 'rank': 0, 'lv': 1, 'star': 2},
            {'power': 25029, 'id': 53, 'skills': "", 'rank': 0, 'lv': 1, 'star': 3}]

for single_partner_info in all_list:
    for each in id_count:
        if ("id", single_partner_info["id"]) in each.items():
            if  ("star", single_partner_info["star"]) in each.items():
                each["count"] +=1
        else:
            id_count.append(dict(id=single_partner_info["id"],
                                star=single_partner_info["star"],
                                    count=1))

print(id_count)
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 33, 'star': 2, 'count': 3}, 
{'id': 49, 'star': 2, 'count': 2}, 
{'id': 53, 'star': 3, 'count': 2}, 
{'id': 53, 'star': 3, 'count': 2}]
```

What I want:

```
[{'id': 33, 'star': 2, 'count': 4}, 
{'id': 49, 'star': 2, 'count': 1}, 
{'id': 53, 'star': 3, 'count': 1}]
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: What should the output be if all_list contains an additional dictionary like: *{'power': 22297, 'id': 49, 'skills': "", 'rank': 0, 'lv': 1, 'star': 2}*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set flag and then update or append the count or values, try below code -

```
for single_partner_info in all_list:
    flag = False
    for each in id_count:
        if each['id'] == single_partner_info['id']:
            each['count'] += 1
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        id_count.append({'id': single_partner_info["id"], 'star': single_partner_info["star"], 'count': 1})

print(id_count)
```

> [{'id': 33, 'star': 2, 'count': 4}, {'id': 49, 'star': 2, 'count': 1}, {'id': 53, 'star': 3, 'count': 1}]

I also have modified your logic, and its also working -

```
for single_partner_info in all_list:
    flag = False
    for each in id_count:
        if ("id", single_partner_info["id"]) in each.items():
            each["count"] +=1
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        id_count.append(dict(id=single_partner_info["id"], star=single_partner_info["star"], count=1))

print(id_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should allow for the case where all_list contains more than one dictionary with equal 'id' and 'star'.

```
id_count = [
    {'id': 33, 'star': 2, 'count': 3}
]

id_all = {(_d['id'], _d['star']): _d['count'] for _d in id_count}


all_list = [
    {'power': 20710, 'id': 33, 'skills': "", 'rank': 0, 'lv': 1, 'star': 2},
    {'power': 22296, 'id': 49, 'skills': "", 'rank': 0, 'lv': 1, 'star': 2},
    {'power': 22297, 'id': 49, 'skills': "", 'rank': 0, 'lv': 1, 'star': 2},
    {'power': 25029, 'id': 53, 'skills': "", 'rank': 0, 'lv': 1, 'star': 3}
]

for _dict in all_list:
    key = _dict['id'], _dict['star']
    id_all[key] = id_all.get(key, 0) + 1

id_count = [{'id': _id, 'star': _star, 'count': _count} for (_id, _star), _count in id_all.items()]

print(id_count)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 33, 'star': 2, 'count': 4}, {'id': 49, 'star': 2, 'count': 2}, {'id': 53, 'star': 3, 'count': 1}]
```